# How to use script in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to use this code in ReactJS how can I use it?

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  var $uploadCrop
  function readFile(input) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
        $('#cropImagePop').modal('show');
        rawImg = e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
  else {
      swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
 }
}
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
viewport: {
    width: 150,
    height: 200,
},
enforceBoundary: false,
enableExif: true
});
}
```

I wrote this code for showing image crop function which is shown in a modal box.

Comment: Hey Dino, welcome to SO. This code makes me a bit sad. jQuery in react, though possible is unnecessary. There are some great react modal implementations, I suggest you go check them out and remove jQuery entirely. If you insist on using jQuery, do **not** at any point modify the DOM manually or by other external tools in a react component, you are asking for trouble.

Comment: can u tell me that can I use this code in ReactJS?

Comment: @Dino The correct answer is not to use this code in react.

Comment: then how can I use this same on react?

Comment: Actually what I want is in this link and I want this in Reactjs----- https://codepen.io/asrulnurrahim/pen/WOyzxy